# Golang : convert Byte slice array to integer array

Tags: http, go

In Golang, the code `[body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)], the ioutil.ReadAll()` returns a byte Slice array, based on the documentation.

This is stored in the variable 'body'. My question is how to convert this  byte Slice array, to an array of Integers.

Comment: Like this: `func convertToArrayOfIntegers(byteslice []b) [3]int { return [3]int{} }`. But this does what you _asked_ for and might not do what you _want_ it to be. Please take the Tour of Go (tour.golang.org) to learn the very basics of the language.

Comment: Thanks Volker for your input, and this link "Tour of Go". I have looked at many tutorials, and it seems Golang has not made a simple function, or one can say, a higher function Abstraction to make a function simple to use, for this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found some code that does what I was wanting:

```
import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
var t = []string{"1", "2", "3"}
var t2 = []int{}

for _, i := range t {
    j, err := strconv.Atoi(i)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    t2 = append(t2, j)
}
fmt.Println(t2)
}
```

---

So this code, does do what I want.

BUT l am disappointed in Golang, for not having a nice one liner that could do this
kind of conversion.
Certain basic things like this, should be packaged up for the programmer, and not have to do this kind of 'low' level programming.

Note, i still like Golang, they had done a lot to make a better C type language that has higher level Data Types when compared to C and also make some things more dynamic compared to C.
SO just disappointed they did not make a High Abstraction for this kind of case, which comes up quite a bit.